# How to concatenate 3 series in python pandas to dataframe based on same id column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have 3 series with different time metrics for each person like so:

Series 1:

[image]

Series 2:

[image]

Series 3:

[image]

I want to merge these series into one dataframe like so:

[image]

I have tried concat but can't seem to merge so that it keeps the 'Name' column as the key id.

Thank you!

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left').merge(df3, on='Name', how='left')`

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting the name column，then concat by column